# setInterval and setTimeout clear

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

Is it necessary to clear the setInterval() and setTimeout() methods before doing next action. Because after doing some animation using setInterval and timeout, I am drawing shapes but it is not working...
So please help me...

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: Use `clearInterval(interval)` and `clearTimeout(timeout)`. Or what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

After setTimeout you do not need to clearTimeout.

clearTimeout is used to cancel a setTimout that has not yet happened or to stop an setInterval with clearInterval.

A setTimeout that has executed is done.

For a better answer you need to provide more code as example.